# Programmatic replacement of Publish date with Modified date does not work outside the_content area

Tags: php, javascript

I am having a problem replacing the Publish date with the Modified date when the theme is created using Avada Theme Builder.

The following code works fine on a theme created with Elementor:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'replace_dates_with_actual_dates');
function replace_dates_with_actual_dates($content) {
    if (is_singular('post')) {
        global $post;
        $s = floor(abs(strtotime($post->post_date) - strtotime($post->post_modified)) / (60 * 60 * 24));
        $pd = get_the_date('F j, Y');
        $md = get_the_modified_date('j. F Y');
        if ($s >= 7) {
            $md = '<b>' . get_the_modified_date('j. F Y') . ' (Update)</b>';
        }
        $content = str_replace($pd, $md, $content);
        return $content;
    }
}
```

However, nothing happens with the Avada theme because the meta information is outside the_content area.

If I replace "$content" with "123" ($content = '123';) the content of the post is replaced with "123". Meta information like date, category and tags are not changed.

I have tried different solutions. ChatGPT also suggested a DOM manipulation (which doesn't work either because then the whole HTML framework is copied into the source code again).

Also, different JavaScript solutions were suggested to me, of which only one solution partially works:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'replace_dates_with_script');
function replace_dates_with_script() {
    if (is_singular('post')) {
        global $post;
        $pd = get_the_date('j. M Y');
        $md = get_the_modified_date('d F Y') . ' (Update)';
        echo '<script>
        (function($) {
          $(window).on("load", function() {
            var originalDate = "' . esc_js($pd) . '";
            var modifiedDate = "' . esc_js($md) . '";
            var dateElements = $("div.fusion-post-title-meta-wrap span:contains(\'" + originalDate + "\')");
            dateElements.text(modifiedDate);
          });
        })(jQuery);
        </script>';
    }
}
```

In this solution, the date is exchanged as desired, but only after moving the mouse or touching the screen on the smartphone.

In the end, ChatGPT gave up because the problem was too complex.

Does anyone have an idea to solve the problem?

Update: 2023/08/27

I forgot to mention that I had initially used “wp_footer”. I had then taken “wp_head” as a test because even with “wp_footer” the date is only changed when you move the mouse or touch the screen. I suspect some conflict with the Avada theme (would not be the first time).